# Graph API method not working

Tags: php, facebook

Just one day before the following codes working for me but now it's not working for me.

```
require 'facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array( 'appId' =>'APPID','secret' => 'some_secret'));
$user = $facebook->getUser();
if ($user){$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');}
```

it's not showing the current loggged in user name or id. Is n't it working anymore ???

Comment: Change your api key ASAP and never post it

Comment: can you suggest me, why this code is not working any more?@Vasfed

Comment: Are there any errors/warnings and what is the expected result?

Comment: it should show the name and id of the logged user.but its not showing .It 's showing blank screen. @Vasfed

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using some deprecated api/code examples, current [facebook docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_retrieve_user_profile) have this snippet:

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '{app-id}',
  'app_secret' => '{app-secret}',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
  ]);

try {
  // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
  $response = $fb->get('/me?fields=id,name', '{access-token}');
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

$user = $response->getGraphUser();
echo 'Name: ' . $user->getName();
```

Comment: Thanks the code working for me. but can you tell me how can i avoid access token expiration? In every one hour or after certain time it is getting expired . thanks in advance.@Vasfed